# Java custom events and logging

Tags: java

I have a simple custom event handler that process' events and passes the event off to the appropriate event processor. So for example, say Event0 triggers 3 other events (Event1, Event2, Event3)

```
public void receive(Event event) {
        synchronized(this){
            this.event = event;
        for(Processor processor : processors){
            if(processor.interestedIn(event)){
                processor.process(this.event);
            }
        }System.out.println("Received Event: " + event);

        }
    }
```

For example sake, let's assume the first event that gets passed through is Event0... loop through the processors to check if all active processors are interested in Event0 and if they are, they process the event.

```
protected Event process(Event event) {
         String parId = event.getId();
        if (event instanceof Event0){
            return new EventA(EventAId(parId), parId, 0);
        }else if (event instanceof Event1){
         return new EventA(EventAId(parId), parId, 0);
        }   throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown event  " + event);
    }
```

Also, assume that i have other processors that fire when EventA is detected.

EventA looks like ...

```
public class EventA implements Event {

    private final String id;
    private final String parentId;
    private final double value;

    public EventA(String id, String parentId, double value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.value= value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**How can I store the entire event chain in a hashmap inside the ChainedEvent object below? -- I am basically wondering where I should place the ChainedEvent constructor and where I should I call the add method on the ChainedEvent object?**

```
public class ChainedEvent implements Event {

    private final String id;
    private final Event parent;
    private final Map<String, Event> children = new HashMap<>();

    public ChainedEvent(String id, Event parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Event getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public ChainedEvent addChild(Event child) {
        children.put(child.getId(), child);
        return this;
    }

    public int size() {
        return children.size();
    }

}
```

Parent would be the first event fired and the children would be the subsequent events fired from processing the parent.

The **System.out.println("Received Event: " + event);** out puts the following when Event0 is sent:

```
Recieved Event: com.x4rq.events.Event0@761b2f32
Recieved Event: com.x4rq.events.EventA@11c0f73a
Recieved Event: com.x4rq.events.EventB@13a709f1
Recieved Event: com.x4rq.events.EventC@3b7db74b
```

as receive(Event event) is triggered multiple times from Event0.. so the output is what I want... now how can I store that into the hashmap inside a ChainedEvent object?

Comment: I'd like a couple of clarifications - I take it from the setup of your `ChainedEvent`, you are only interested in chains that are 2 `Event`s long?  i.e. you only want to capture the `Event0` and its children in your example?  If this is the case, can you clarify why simply holding on to a reference to `EventA` and then querying its `getParent()` is not enough?

Comment: Two events "long" is an example. Based on the processor it can be even longer.. ie. Event0 -> EventA -> EventC -> EventD

Comment: OK - got it. I see the clarification to the question, too.  FWIW - that's exactly the question I was pondering - where do you want the constructor.  Do you always know the "start of chain" will be an `Event0`? Or at least within a definite set of `Event` types that you're handling within your `Processor`?

Comment: Right now there's four different event types. Is it easier if the types are fixed? I'd like to write it so it doesn't matter how many types. I'm also having difficulty figuring out how to programmatically determine the start of the chain.

Comment: OK - I've answered based on your question as it stands.  I'm curious, though - I can't see the context where you want to do this.  In particular, you seem to be duplicating function - you can work out a chain from your `Event` objects, by following `parentId` until you get a null, but you also implement `ChainedEvent` which implements the `Event` interface too - is it also designed to be handled by your event `Processor` (i.e. triggered separately to the events within it?)

Answer (score 0):

I think your fundamental issues are twofold:

1. How to determine whether an even is "top of chain" and should instantiate a new ChainedEvent.
2. If an event is not "top of chain" how to find the ChainedEvent to which it should be added.

### 1. Start a new chain

The first is easier.  I think you need to do this in your `Processor.process()` method.  If an event is "top of chain" then instantiate a ChainedEvent object, otherwise add the event as a child.  Here's an idea how you might do that:

```
protected Event process(Event event) {
         String parId = event.getId();
        ChainedEvent thisEventsChain;
        if (event.getParentId() == null) //assuming parent is null for top of chain
                                         //could equally test
                                         // event.getParentId().equals("");
        {
            thisEventsChain = new ChainedEvent(parId,event)
        }

        if (event instanceof Event0){
            Event childEvent = new EventA(EventAId(parId), parId, 0);
            thisChainedEvent.addChild(childEvent);
            return childEvent;
        }else if (event instanceof Event1){
            Event childEvent = new EventA(EventAId(parId), parId, 0);
            thisChainedEvent.addChild(childEvent);
            return childEvent;
        }   throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown event  " + event);
    }
```

### 2. Find chain for child

You probably need to add a new method to your Event interface.  I'd recommend `getEventChain()`. Each event can store a reference to the ChainedEvent to which it belongs and return this.  In fact, this could return null for "top of chain" events - removing the need to test `ParentId` as in **1.** above.  Thus, in your `Processor.process()`, if you're dealing with an event which already has a ChainedEvent, you add children to that - if it doesn't have a `ChainedEvent`, you instantiate one.